# Generate a TOC (index.org) file out our headings from all org files

Tags: org-mode

Currently i have around 25 org files each with multiple headings. Everytime i want to go over my notes, i need to *remember* the name of the file and open it (faster if its in buffer, else i need to go to the org folder)

Is there a way to generate a TOC of files/heading1 for all files under the `org-directory` and place it under an `index.org`?

P.S: Google did not return any good package!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of options. I would not create a permanent index.org file, because it would take some extra effort to keep it up to to date. If you don't mind installing f.el and helm, here is a dynamic way to get a list of all the headings.

```
(defun org-toc ()
  "Generate a table of contents for org-files in this directory."
  (interactive)
  (let ((org-agenda-files (f-entries "." (lambda (f) (f-ext? f "org")) t)))
    (helm-org-agenda-files-headings)))
```

If you really want a buffer with headlines, you could try this approach to make a temporary buffer with links to the headlines:

```
(defun org-toc ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((headings (delq nil (loop for f in (f-entries "." (lambda (f) (f-ext? f "org")) t)
                  append
                  (with-current-buffer (find-file-noselect f)
                    (org-map-entries
                     (lambda ()
                       (when (> 2 (car (org-heading-components)))
                     (cons f (nth 4 (org-heading-components)))))))))))
    (switch-to-buffer (get-buffer-create "*toc*"))
    (erase-buffer)
    (org-mode)
    (loop for (file . heading) in headings 
      do
      (insert (format "* [[%s::*%s]]\n" file heading)))))
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried the second solution and spacemacs just hangs! Its clocking at 98% since sometime now..

Comment: Please note, i have around 28 files totaling to 1.2MB

Comment: It takes about 10 seconds to list 3541 headings from 35 files that are 2.4MB in size on my mac. It is for sure not the speediest method.

Comment: sorry my bad. The script was running from my home dir and hence taking too long.

Comment: That is because the f-files function works recursively in that function!

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach I have used:

```
(defun org-toc ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((files (f-entries "." (lambda (f) (f-ext? f "org")) t))
    (headlines '())
    choice) 
    (loop for file in files do
      (with-temp-buffer 
        (insert-file-contents file) 
        (goto-char (point-min))
        (while (re-search-forward org-heading-regexp nil t)
          (cl-pushnew (list
               (format "%-80s (%s)"
                   (match-string 0)
                   (file-name-nondirectory file))
               :file file
               :position (match-beginning 0))
              headlines))))
    (setq choice
      (completing-read "Headline: " (reverse headlines)))
    (find-file (plist-get (cdr (assoc choice headlines)) :file))
    (goto-char (plist-get (cdr (assoc choice headlines)) :position))))
```

if you have helm or ivy setup to do completion, it should use them to help pick the headlines. This takes about 4-5 seconds for me on about 3500 headlines.